# d3 all branches on top of each other vertical dendogram. r2d3 shiny

Tags: r, d3.js, tree, shiny

I want to make a vertical dendogram, however all branches are on top of each other, and I don't understand why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJoME.png)

this is a dendogram based on the flare dataset...
The code is meant to go into a shiny app, and that is why i use r2d3. Not sure if this makes a huge difference as the .js doesn't show the proper tree anyway.

the code I use right now is:

```
// !preview r2d3 data = read.csv("flare.csv"), d3_version = 4
// Based on: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(300,10)");

var tree = d3.tree()
  .size([0,200])
  //.size([height, width - 160]);
  .separation(function separation(a, b) {return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1) ;});

var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

r2d3.onRender(function(data, svg, w, h, options) {
  var root = stratify(data)
      .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.height - b.height) || a.id.localeCompare(b.id); });

  root = tree(root);

  var y_spanning = 0.4;

  var link = g.selectAll(".link")
  .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) / y_spanning
        //return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
        + "C" + (d.parent.x ) + "," + (d.y )  / y_spanning
        //+ "C" + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.x
        + " " + (d.parent.x ) + "," + (d.parent.y ) / y_spanning
        //+ " " + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.parent.x
        + " " + (d.parent.x ) + "," + d.parent.y / y_spanning;
        //+ " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
      });


//  link.append("text")
//    .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x; })
//    .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y; })
//    .attr("font-size", 2 + 4 * height / 500)
//    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
//    .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") +     1);
//    });

 // var linkText = g.selectAll(".link")
 //   .append("text")
 //   .attr("class", "link-label")
 //   //.attr("dy", ".35em")
 //   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 //   .text(function(d) {
 //       return d.parentId;
 //   });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--    internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y / y_spanning + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 15)
      .attr("dy", 4)
      .attr("font-size", 2 + 4 * height / 500)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -20 : 20; })
      //.style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });

});
```

Comment: Please supply a link to the dataset, or is it the dataset used in your bl.ocks starter?

Answer (score 0):

You have just swap the 'x' and 'y' coords and tweak the curve between.

A screenshot of the result:
[image]

I did not manage to  get a running snippet while loading the original CSV used in the bl.ocks.org sample

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Just run the example from own local web server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- horizontal version https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #999;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.node--internal circle {
  fill: #555;
}

.node--internal text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: 0.4;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="2000" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,40)");

var tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([width-40, height -160]);

var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

d3.csv("flare.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = stratify(data)
      .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.height - b.height) || a.id.localeCompare(b.id); });

  tree(root);

  var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
            + "C" +  d.x + "," + (d.parent.y + 100)
            + " " + d.parent.x + "," + (d.parent.y + 100)
            + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
      });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.children ? "45" : "90") + ")"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually started from a horizontal to a vertical tree, by switching the x and y.

I found the problem: It was about sorting the data properly. parents and childs should be in the correct order, otherwise it doesn't work properly.