# D3 v4 Tree -- Adding Clarity

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a Tree Diagram (originally based on https://bl.ocks.org/tejaser/55c43b4a9febca058363a5e58edbce81)

I have flipped the orientation to be top-down, but I need to work on the appearance of the child nodes -- when the entire tree is extended, the labels overlap and you can't really see which labels go to what node.

I'm not sure if I should modify how the path is calculated, or if there is a way to add a repelling force per each node so there's definitely a minimum space between nodes. Thoughts?

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/2t13ryh6/

Text:

```
// Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children ? -20 : 20; })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "middle" : "middle";
      }) 
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; }) 
        .style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.data.female/(d.data.value))});
```

Comment: you have to orient these texts vertical, have a look at this question how it is done https://stackoverflow.com/q/51941373/9938317

Comment: or this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640430/9938317

Comment: I definitely love the idea of transforming the text to be vertical. This helps clear things up, but I'm still getting some overlap. I've updated the JSFiddle to show the text swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with the rotation angle (-90) and `text-anchor`, `dx` and `dy`

And maybe the `y` position, I have disabled it for this demo.

```
  nodeEnter.append('text')
     .attr("dy", "0.2em")
     .attr("dx", "-1.3em")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.children ? "0" : "-90") + ")"; })
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.children ? -20 : 0; })
     .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "end";
      }) 
     .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; }) 
     .style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.data.female/(d.data.value))});
```